# `"` replaced with `&quot;` when loading page

Tags: jsf-2, utf-8, xhtml, glassfish-3, quotes

I've stumbled on a little problem when i'm viewing my page where `"` gets replaced with `&quot;`. My page looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='case']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        if(test == "daglig"){

            $("div.desc").hide();
            $("#daglig_div").show();

        }else if(test == "veckovis"){

            $("div.desc").hide();
            $("#veckovis_div").show();

        }else if(test == "manadsvis"){

            $("div.desc").hide();
            $("#manadsvis_div").show();

        }
    });
});
```

When i'm deploying the page the result is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(&quot;input[name$='case']&quot;).click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        if(test == &quot;daglig&quot;){

            $(&quot;div.desc&quot;).hide();
            $(&quot;#daglig_div&quot;).show();

        }else if(test == &quot;veckovis&quot;){

            $(&quot;div.desc&quot;).hide();
            $(&quot;#veckovis_div&quot;).show();

        }else if(test == &quot;manadsvis&quot;){

            $(&quot;div.desc&quot;).hide();
            $(&quot;#manadsvis_div&quot;).show();

        }
    });
});​
```

And it's only this part of the page which gets this strange convertion. I've tried with different encodings, charsets, copying other quotes on the page which doesn't get replaced with `&quot;`, replaced `"` with `&#34;` and i still get the same error. Can someone please help me on this matter?

Thanks in advance, ClydeFrog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "rewrote" the function again myself and it's working now. Apparently the old text had different charsets then my new text i wrote. Very strange bacause i converted the old text to "UTF-8" with notepad++, but obviously it didn't work... thanks anyway to everyone who took the time :)